# Starting Darkice automatically via daemontools

Tags: raspbian

I have installed and configured [darkice](https://code.google.com/p/darkice/) in [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) and it works fine if I run it with "sudo darkice". I want to run darkice automatically so I tried to run it via [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) with the following steps but it is not working. please help.

1. open a shell to your server, and type the following:

   ```
   apt-get install daemontools
   apt-get install daemontools-run
   mkdir /etc/service/darkice
   chmod 2775 /etc/service/darkice
   touch /etc/service/darkice/run
   ```
2. `vi /etc/service/darkice/run` and add these lines:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo Running service
   exec darkice
   ```

Comment: Please describe what you mean with "it is not working". Do you get an error message? Or will it simply not start when you reboot the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make the `run` script executable:

```
chmod 755 /etc/service/darkice/run
```